# Vectorized (partial) inverse of an N*M*M tensor with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, vectorization

I'm almost exactly in a similar situation as the asker here over a year ago:
[fast way to invert or dot kxnxn matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284421/fast-way-to-invert-or-dot-kxnxn-matrix)

So I have a tensor with indices a[n,i,j] of dimensions (N,M,M) and I want to invert the M*M square matrix part for each n in N.

For example, suppose I have

```
In [1]:    a = np.arange(12)
           a.shape = (3,2,2)
           a

Out[1]: array([[[ 0,  1],
                  [ 2,  3]],

                  [[ 4,  5],
                  [ 6,  7]],

                  [[ 8,  9],
                  [10, 11]]])
```

Then a for loop inversion would go like this:

```
In [2]: inv_a = np.zeros([3,2,2])
        for m in xrange(0,3):
            inv_a[m] = np.linalg.inv(a[m])
        inv_a

Out[2]: array([[[-1.5,  0.5],
                  [ 1. ,  0. ]],

                  [[-3.5,  2.5],
                  [ 3. , -2. ]],

                  [[-5.5,  4.5],
                 [ 5. , -4. ]]])
```

This will apparently be implemented in NumPy 2.0, according to [this issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2216) on github...

I guess I need to install the dev version as seberg noted in the github issue thread, but is there another way to do this in *vectorized* manner right now?

Comment: The answer is no, but it isn't that bad: [Gauss-Jordan matrix inversion is an O(`M`^3) operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra), so it is going to dominate performance unless `N` >>> `M`^3.

Comment: Thanks for the good point, Jaime! Incidentally, N would be around 10^3...10^5 and M between 2...6 and maybe much higher later when I get my code working properly...

Comment: If the main for loop is the issue, maybe Cython could help. There will be a Python function call in the middle of the for loop, but it should still be moderately faster.

Comment: Given that this has been "fixed" in an upcoming release I don't know if it is worth trying to be too clever.  However, you can think of your matrix as block diagonal or as banded.  There ARE routines in scipy.linalg for banded matrices.  Since M is not too large you may be able to use them (solved_banded, for example, others if there is more structure to your matrices).  Of course you would also have to build the banded matrix, there will still be a lot of zeros in the bands, etc. so I don't know if you will win in the end.

Comment: Hmm good point, Craig... I think I'll give the banded matrix a go! I guess generating very large zero arrays isn't very time consuming...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**
In NumPy 1.8 and later, the functions in `numpy.linalg` are generalized universal functions.
Meaning that you can now do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(12, 3, 3)
np.linalg.inv(a)
```

This will invert each 3x3 array and return the result as a 12x3x3 array.
See the [numpy 1.8 release notes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.8.0-notes.rst#new-features).

---

**Original Answer:**

Since `N` is relatively small, how about we compute the LU decomposition manually for all the matrices at once.
This ensures that the for loops involved are relatively short.

Here's how this can be done with normal NumPy syntax:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand

def pylu3d(A):
    N = A.shape[1]
    for j in xrange(N-1):
        for i in xrange(j+1,N):
            #change to L
            A[:,i,j] /= A[:,j,j]
            #change to U
            A[:,i,j+1:] -= A[:,i,j:j+1] * A[:,j,j+1:]

def pylusolve(A, B):
    N = A.shape[1]
    for j in xrange(N-1):
        for i in xrange(j+1,N):
            B[:,i] -= A[:,i,j] * B[:,j]
    for j in xrange(N-1,-1,-1):
        B[:,j] /= A[:,j,j]
        for i in xrange(j):
            B[:,i] -= A[:,i,j] * B[:,j]

#usage
A = rand(1000000,3,3)
b = rand(3)
b = np.tile(b,(1000000,1))
pylu3d(A)
# A has been replaced with the LU decompositions
pylusolve(A, b)
# b has been replaced to the solutions of
# A[i] x = b[i] for each A[i] and b[i]
```

As I have written it, `pylu3d` modifies A in place to compute the LU decomposition.
After replacing each `N`x`N` matrix with its LU decomposition, `pylusolve` can be used to solve an `M`x`N` array `b` representing the right hand sides of your matrix systems.
It modifies `b` in place and does the proper back substitutions to solve the system.
As it is written, this implementation does not include pivoting, so it isn't numerically stable, but it should work well enough in most cases.

Depending on how your array is arranged in memory, it is probably still a good bit faster to use Cython.
Here are two Cython functions that do the same thing, but they iterate along `M` first.
It's not vectorized, but it is relatively fast.

```
from numpy cimport ndarray as ar
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def lu3d(ar[double,ndim=3] A):
    cdef int n, i, j, k, N=A.shape[0], h=A.shape[1], w=A.shape[2]
    for n in xrange(N):
        for j in xrange(h-1):
            for i in xrange(j+1,h):
                #change to L
                A[n,i,j] /= A[n,j,j]
                #change to U
                for k in xrange(j+1,w):
                    A[n,i,k] -= A[n,i,j] * A[n,j,k]

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def lusolve(ar[double,ndim=3] A, ar[double,ndim=2] b):
    cdef int n, i, j, N=A.shape[0], h=A.shape[1]
    for n in xrange(N):
        for j in xrange(h-1):
            for i in xrange(j+1,h):
                b[n,i] -= A[n,i,j] * b[n,j]
        for j in xrange(h-1,-1,-1):
            b[n,j] /= A[n,j,j]
            for i in xrange(j):
                b[n,i] -= A[n,i,j] * b[n,j]
```

You could also try using Numba, though I couldn't get it to run as fast as Cython in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot IanH for your great solutions! I think explicit inversion formulae for fairly small matrices will be even faster than the pylusolve method(?) I haven't gotten to know Cython yet, but I'll try that too ASAP. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Also, on the explicit inversion formulae, the catch is that you'd have to implement them on an individual basis, but you probably already knew that. I'm not totally sure which will be faster, the lusolve function takes the place of multiplication by the inverses. Both operations are O(N^3), but matrix multiplication functions are usually well-optimized, so there could be some speed gain. It probably will depend on how the data is arranged in memory.